# Google Apps Script, concatenation with .map() method

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, concatenation

Im trying to do a concatenation of two strings in apps script using map method, but im having the following:

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

Does anybody knows how I could do it? Thanks!

```
var master_ga = ss.getSheetByName("master_CampaignConversions");

  var master_ga_numRows = master_ga.getLastRow();
  var master_ga_lc = master_ga.getLastColumn();
  var master_ga_values = master_ga.getRange(1, 1, master_ga_numRows, master_ga_lc).getValues();

  var data_ga = master_ga.getRange(2, 4, master_ga_numRows-1, 1).getValues();  
  var results_ga = data_ga.map(function(r) {return [r[0][0] +"_"+ r[3][0]]});

  master_ga.getRange(2, 16, master_ga_numRows-1, results_ga[0].length).setValues(results_ga);
```

Comment: In your script, you retrieve the values from "D2:D". From this, I cannot understand what you want to do with `data_ga.map(function(r) {return [r[0][0] +"_"+ r[3][0]]})`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? By the way, the document of `map` can be seen at [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var master_ga=ss.getSheetByName("master_CampaignConversions");
  var master_ga_numRows = master_ga.getLastRow();
  var master_ga_lc = master_ga.getLastColumn();
  var master_ga_values = master_ga.getRange(1, 1, master_ga_numRows, master_ga_lc).getValues();
  var data_ga = master_ga.getRange(2, 4, master_ga_numRows-1, 1).getValues();  
  var results_ga = data_ga.map(function(r) {return [r[0] +"_"+ r[3]]});//just one index required
  master_ga.getRange(2, 16, master_ga_numRows-1, results_ga[0].length).setValues(results_ga);
```